# Why are Windows 10 transparency effects temperamental?

Tags: windows, aero, transparency, visual-effects

- The "Transparency Effects" (aka Acrylic, Aero Glass, Frosted Glass, Translucency, Background Blur, etc) in Windows 10 *sometimes* (but not always) do not work on my computer, despite the *Transparency Effects* toggle in the Windows 10 Settings App **always** being enabled.
- PC specs:

  - Intel Core i7-6850K
  - Intel X99 motherboard chipset
  - Two NVIDIA GeForce 1080 Ti cards

    - SLI bridge attached, but SLI is disabled.
    - NVIDIA GeForce driver version 456.38

      - This issue happens whatever version of the NVIDIA GeForce drivers I'm using, going back at least a year. It also happens with the older driver version 432.00 which is unique to stock Windows 10 installs.
  - I am running Windows 10 Version 2004, though this issue also happened in Version 1809.
- My PC is a desktop, not a laptop. There are no *onboard graphics*. I always use the "Ultimate Performance" power-plan so the Windows 10 power-saver should never be applied.

  - I mention this because Windows 10 *does* disable transparency effects if it detects you're using a laptop on battery power.

---

Additionally:

- Sometimes it works, sometimes it does not work.

  - I can't find any obvious trigger or cause for it to work sometimes.
- Temperatures inside my computer (CPU and GPU temperatures) are all within normal ranges.
- Component voltages are also within acceptable range.
- I am not employing any overclocking of my GPU or CPU, though I am using XMP memory settings.
- I had a support chat with NVIDIA and their rep said this was a bug in Windows and not NVIDIA's drivers, but didn't provide any further information.
- *Yes*, I ran `sfc /scannow` and the only issue that was logged to `CBS.log` was a broken OneDrive start-menu shortcut.
- I don't have any registry changes applied that override DWM settings, such as:

  - `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize\EnableTransparency`
  - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\UseOLEDTaskbarTransparency`
- Running the Windows 10 Color Calibration tool had no effect.

---

### Screenshot proof:

The calculator window should have the transparency effect applied to it, but notice how it is entirely opaque:

[image]

This is how it is supposed to look (after I restarted my computer a couple of times the transparency effects were working again)

[image]

---

The taskbar should also blur the desktop underneath it, but its entirely opaque - also notice that the Start Menu tile *hot-tracking* (aka hover) effect doesn't bleed onto the other tiles (only the currently hovered title has a white border, highlighted in the red circle):

[image]

This is how it's supposed to look (notice the subtle edge shading on the top-right corner of the Remote Desktop Connection tile)

[image]

---

System control panel and About Windows dialog:

[image]

---

Not using Power Saver:

[image]

Comment: Yep, Windows is sometimes like that. Try a third party tool such as Ultimate Windows Tweaker, https://www.thewindowsclub.com/ultimate-windows-tweaker-4-windows-10 , or Open Shell Menu, https://open-shell.github.io/Open-Shell-Menu/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I already use those :) But they don't help the underlying problem of Windows not enabling Transparency Effects. I don't actually care either way if my windows have fancy effects on them or not, but I'm actually far more interested in understanding why this Windows feature is not working as-intended because it can be a sign of _other things_ being broken or misconfigured.